# How do I dereference the address returned by a pointer from a function that takes an int & a pointer of type struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dereference

I am passing an int & a pointer to a struct into a function that returns a pointer to data in the struct. How do I dereference the address returned by the pointer?

i have created a search function to look for a node in a linked list. this is my search function:

```
Entry* search(int num, Entry* &head)
{
    Entry *current;

    current = head;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(atoi(current->number) == num)
        {
            return(current); //selected node is found
        }
        current = current->next; //move to next node to check for num
    }

    return head;//if not found return head of linked list
}
```

My problem is in trying to get the value for the pointer returned from:

```
cout << (search(searchNum, listHead));
```

the statement above returns the address to the value returned by the pointer in the function like this:

```
0x100300000
```

so i tried different variations of something like this:

```
cout << *(search(searchNum, listHead));
```

but i only get errors....

can anyone help me figure out how to get the value from the pointer being returned?

ultimately, id like to finish it off with something like this:

```
found = search(searchNum, listHead);
cout << "The number you searched for is: " << *found;
```

but it just aint happening :/

thanks guys. I'm a newbie so please forgive me for being completely off base on any of this... i tried to search for a similar question but just could not get any clear answer... maybe its true what joel spolsky said about pointers... some people are missing a part in their brains that makes them understand them... :/

Comment: how'bout `cout << found->number`?

Comment: what i don't understand though, is if my search function is returning an address to ....


ok wait.... I'm going to try to explain it based on what you just taught me. basically, my function is returning an address to a node...i just have to dereference the data inside the struct with -> to access the data...

you are a genius, thanks for teaching me with your insight. i swear, it feels like the cosmos of pointers just opened up in my brain. the whole time i was returning the entire node, and i didn't realize i had to access the CONTENTS of that node!!! i can't express my gratitude enough!!!!

Comment: [OT]: You may remove reference (`&`) in your function prototype: `Entry* search(int num, Entry* head)` is enough.

Comment: BTW, I would return `nullptr` when not found (so you have to test pointer on return before dereference it).

Comment: Mouze and the Paramegnetic Croissant are correct, but FWIW another alternative is to teach the compiler how to output `Entry` objects: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Entry& e) { return os << "{ number " << e.number << ", next " << e.next << " }"; }`... might be convenient for logging / debugging your linked list.

Comment: if you down voted this could you provide some feedback as to why you thought this was a bad questions please.....? I understand this is ultimately a braindead oversight on my part for not realizing the function was returning the whole node and i would like to understand why you do not think this question could be of value to others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cout << "The number you searched for is: " << found->number;
```

or

```
cout << "The number you searched for is: " << (*found).number;
```

Comment: if you use Visual Studio, you can add custom visualization of your own data structure. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx